# Are normal ghouls' claws considered magic for the purposes of DR?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, damage-reduction

Ghouls are undead, magical by nature.  They have claws that can cause paralysis. However, this requires a fortitude save and leads me to believe it is not a magical effect.

Can their claws overcome DR X/Magic on other creatures/NPCs/players if they are just a regular old ghoul?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Some monsters are vulnerable to magic weapons. Any weapon with at
>   least a +1 magical enhancement bonus on attack and damage rolls
>   overcomes the damage reduction of these monsters. Such creatures’
>   natural weapons (but not their attacks with weapons) are treated as
>   magic weapons for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

This is the general rule. Ghoul's statblock does not mention DR/magic and does not explicitly list its attacks as magical (they have a supernatural disease rider, but that's beside the point), so no, **its attacks do *not* overcome DR/magic of other creatures.**